# Efficiency way to clean data in R

Tags: r

Input is

[image]

the row 3 and row 5 had incorrtct format,
if I want

| sale_date | produst_model | store_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20210208 | ASUS_DE552 | AAE_08072 |
| 20210305 | ASUS_AC693 | AAE_08072 |
| 20210107 | ASUS_DE551 | AAR_7461 |
| 20210325 | ASUS_DB341 | CMHT_654 |
| 20210227 | ASUS_HG0982 | BR_981 |

If this table have 20,000 rows, Do I have more efficiency way to check every row is match rule?

Comment: It would be easier to help if we didn't each need to type your input data in. Can you please provide as code we can load to get an unambiguous copy of your sample data?

Comment: @Jon Spring
 For now, I using ifelse to label nchar(df$sale_date) == 8 then to pick this to deal with. But it takes me half an hour only correct 200 rows.

Comment: I guess that the strings in three columns were at some point extracted from a composite string such as `20210227_ASUS_HG0982_BR_981` but the extraction seems to gone wrong in some places. If this assumption is correct then go back to the original strings and fix the extraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the data posted my hunch is that the strings in the three columns were at some point extracted from a composite string such as `20210227_ASUS_HG0982_BR_981` but the extraction seems to have gone wrong in some places. If this assumption is correct then I would recommend going back to the original strings and fixing the extraction, for example like this using the `extract` function:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(original) %>%
  extract(original,
          into = c("sale_date", "produst_model", "store_code"),
          regex = "(\\d+)_(\\w+\\d+)_(\\w+)")
  sale_date produst_model store_code
1  20210227   ASUS_HG0982     BR_981
```

Data:

```
original = "20210227_ASUS_HG0982_BR_981"
```

Obviously, the regex here is based only on a single string and will likely have to be adapted as soon as you have more strings.